# Create a nested array from flat array using children

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a question regarding nested arrays ; I searched on google and stackoverflow but could not find a solution that fits my need :-/

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Europe
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => West
                    [1] => East
                    [2] => South
                    [3] => North
                    [4] => Zimbabwe
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => West
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Germany
                    [1] => France
                    [2] => Switzerland
                    [3] => Netherlands
                    [4] => Belgium
                    [5] => Luxembourg
                    [6] => United Kingdom
                    [7] => Ireland
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Germany
            [children] => 
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => France
            [children] => 
        )
)
```

I would like to transform it to have it nested, meaning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Europe
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
            (
               [name] => West
               [children] => Array
                (
                  [0]=> Array
                  (
                    [name] => Germany
                  )
                  [1]=> Array
                  (
                    [name] => France
                  )
                )
            )
                    [2] => Array
            (
               [name] => East
               [children] => Array
                (
                  [0]=> Array
                  (
                    [name] => Poland
                  )
                  [1]=> Array
                  (
                    [name] => Austria
                  )
                )
            )
        )
        )
)
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you could use loops inside loops until you reach the part where you need to modify your array.

Comment: hello fab, actually I did not tried anything yet. To be honest I don't know how to begin... Should this be a recursive function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($unnested_ary as $one_k => $one_v)
{
    foreach ($one_v as $two_k => $two_v)
    {
        if ($two_k == 'children')
        {
            foreach ($two_v as $three_k => $three_v)
            {
                $unnested_array[$one_k][$two_k][$three_k][] = array(array(
                    'name' => $three_v
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I nested it properly, but you should get the idea and play around with this code. This should basically create new keys and values like you asked.

Comment: Hello Dugi, thanks for your response. Actually I thought I should use a recursive function cause I do not know in advance the number of levels that I will have. My array was just an example. I tried the following but it does not work properly: function buildTree($inputarray)
{
 $arrayout=array();
 foreach ($inputarray as $arrayelt)
 {
   if (is_array($arrayelt['children']))
   {
     $arrayout['name']=$inputarray['name'];
     buildTree($inputarray['children']);
   }
   else
   {
     $arrayout['name']=$inputarray['name'];
   }
 }
 
 return $arrayout;
}